# How to accomplish auto update in an AvaloniaUI app?

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I am about to write a first Avalonia app for android. Ideally the app would check for updates on startup and updates itself or asks the user for it. Does something like click-once deployment exist for Avalonia?
It is an in-house app, so no Google play store.
If this is not possible, what would be another good approach to keep the app up-to-date without reminding users to download the latest apk?